# Why do the google translate and the Microsoft bing translate lack a “and” as I think the 慣れ is a continuative form connecting two phrases?

Tags: translation

> Original Japanese:
> やがて、そんな生活に**慣れ**はじめると、今度は物事をじっくりと考えることが苦痛になってきた。
>
> Google translate: Eventually, as I began to get used to such a life, it became painful to think about things.
>
> Microsoft translate: Before long, when I began to get used to such a life, it became painful to think about things carefully this time.
>
> My own very very rough translation EDITED: In the end, that sort of life when I start to grow accustom to it, now without rushing everything my thoughts gradually become agony.

Why do the google translate and the Microsoft bing translate lack a “and” as I think the 慣れ is a continuative form connecting two phrases?

Comment: Toyu_Frey, you'd better read a simple textbook again and solidify the basics before trying real novels for native speakers. This usage of 始める is a JLPT N4 grammar point. This こと is a nominalizer, which is also N4. I feel you are learning inefficiently because the learning resource you're using doesn't match your level...

Comment: @naruto I admit to sometimes not connecting what I've been taught in terms of the basics with what I read, and it is a ongoing issue. What kind of book or story would be appropriate to attempt translating for me, if not the one I have atm?

Comment: @naruto I understood that the koto is a nominalizer when I translated the sentence the first time, my notes have "to think/to remember verb; after an inflectable word, creates a noun phrase indicating something the speaker does not feel close to; ga particle; " for the "考えることが" segment of the original Japanese.

Comment: As I said, you have to **master** the basic grammar before trying long sentences. You seem to vaguely remember you learned about ～始める and こと somewhere in your classes, but you still cannot use them to make a reasonable translation. (By the way, 考える does not mean "remember".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verb stem + はじめる is a standard grammar pattern which means "to start/begin doing verb".

So, even though you really shouldn't be trusting Bing and Google translate, in this case they have got it right.

Comment: I don't trust em, only using them to double check my translations when I find a roadblock in translation, lol. Thanks for the help!